# VB.net TCP error Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

When i try to set a server listening on a port it gives me the error thats in the title. But i tried some other ports and then i get the same error.

I also tried using netstat to see if those ports are being used, but they dont so that cant be the problem either.

So i think my code is not working correctly

here is my code:

```
    Private Sub Form1_shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    'Pase ip and port
    ServerPort = PortTextbox.Text
    ServerIp = IPAddress.Parse(IpTextbox.Text)
    ServerIpString = IpTextbox.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ConnectToServer("RamonRobben")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    StartServer()
End Sub

Private Sub StartServer()
    'start server and run doListen in thread
    Listener = New TcpListener(ServerIp, ServerPort)
    Listener.Start() 'Start listening on server ERROR ERROR: occures here.
    ListenThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf DoListen)
    ListenThread.IsBackground = False
    ListenThread.Start()
    UpdateGUI("Change", "ServerStatusTxt", "Server Status: Running")
End Sub
```

## DoListen Event

```
    Private Sub DoListen()

    If Listener.Pending = True Then
        'client is the Tcpclient that is accepted by the server
        Dim Client As TcpClient = Listener.AcceptTcpClient

        'start a networkstream to get the message of the client
        Dim Stream As NetworkStream = Client.GetStream()

        'set max-buffer size for data so server will not be overloaded with data
        Dim BufferSize(1024) As Byte

        'put message in data variable so we can read it
        Dim Message As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BufferSize, 0, BufferSize.Length)
        UpdateGUI("Add", "Listbox1", Date.Now + " | " + Message)

        'send response just for fun maby to verify that the message has been received...


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which ports did you try? Please show us also the code of DoListen. The message tells that you try to listen on a port where an application is already listening.

Comment: Yea sure but my code doesnt even reach the DoListen event xD it stops at Listener.start but i will include it :). And i tried th ports: 5012, 4896, 3989, 2617, 8080

Comment: You should use free ports (49152–65535) and please check if your firewall is running.

Comment: And somehow you put a string to an integer (ServerPort = PortTextbox.Text). I think you deactivated some compiler-warnings...

Comment: i have also tried (ServerPort = 5012) because i tought that the textbox could not be converted to a integer but thats not the case

Comment: My firewall isnt running and it did ask for internet permissions but the free ports dont work either...

Comment: Do you start your listener twice? Could you please append the complete stack-trace.

Comment: I finaly fixed the problem by restarting my pc. I think the listener was not closed but also not visible anymore to cmd.

Comment: Then you missed to abort your threads properly. Don't forget to answer your question to yourself ;)